# javascript array pop without another foreach loop

Tags: arrays, javascript

my test array has multiple objects in them that I want to iterate over and if a condition is not met I want to pop it from main array. 
I am using foreach loop. so

so I am using a foreach loop and doing

```
$.foreach(test, function(idx, val){
  if(true){
         test.splice(idx, 1);
  }
});
```

problem is that it doesn’t work as if there are two objects for example, as shown below, it will reindex the array after the first iteration and then the second iteration which will be idx 1, will not be able to do 
test.spice(1,1) since index 1 does not exist in the array anymore.

Now I know that I can create a temporary place holder and the indexes there and then run another foreach but thats what I am trying to avoid. Any ideas will be appreciated

```
[
                     email: “testemail@emailcom”
                     firstName: “Test"
]
[
                     email: “testemail2@emailcom”
                     firstName: “Test"
]
```

Comment: How about using [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead? Unless you really have to mutate the array.

Comment: `for (var i=test.length-1;i>=0;i--){}`

Comment: Isn't it completely obvious that you're both iterating *and* modifying the array at the same time ? Doesn't this ring a bell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove elements from an array, I recommend you to use filter function

```
test = test.filter(function(val, idx) {
  if(true) { // a condition about val
    return false; // return false to EXCLUDE
  } else {
    return true; // return false to INCLUDE
  }
});
```

Comment: Filtering and reassigning is not exactly the same thing. Why do you recommend this method? Here is a perf (http://jsperf.com/array-mutations) it doesn't seem to help performance, especially as the array grows very large.

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate through the array backwards. Then, removing elements from the array only affects the indices of elements that the loop has already dealt with:

```
for (var idx = test.length-1; idx>=0; idx--){
   if(true){
         test.splice(idx, 1);
   }
}
```